# Calling methods of @functions on Razor issue

Tags: c#, razor

this is my first post on Stackoverflow so I apologize for any errors on this post (And sorry for my English too).

I'm having a problem using C# functions on Razor. I have a form with some textboxes to fill them with data from a SQL Server database. I also have some buttons to move across the elements on the DB table (like previous, next, first...).

I'll show you the code:

```
    @{  var codcur = "";
        var descripcion = "";
        var horas = "";
        var tutor = "";
        int pos = 0;  

        if(IsPost) {
            pos = Convert.ToInt32(Session["position"]);
        }
        else {
            pos = 0;
        }

        using(PracticaRazor2.ModeloOcupacional Contexto = new PracticaRazor2.ModeloOcupacional()) {
            var registro = (from cur in Contexto.CURSOS orderby cur.COD_CUR select cur).Skip(pos).First();
            codcur = registro.COD_CUR;
            descripcion = registro.DESCRIPCION;
            horas = registro.HORAS.ToString();
            tutor = registro.TUTOR;
        }





        <h1>Mantenimiento cursos</h1>
        <form action="~/Cursos.cshtml" method="post">
            <label>Código curso:</label>
            <input type="text" name="cod_cur" id="cod_cur" value="@codcur" /><br />
            <label>Descripción:</label>
            <input type="text" name="descripcion" id="descripcion" value="@descripcion" /><br />
            <label>Horas:</label>
            <input type="text" name="horas" id="horas" value="@horas" /><br />
            <label>Tutor:</label>
            <input type="text" name="tutor" id="tutor" value="@tutor" /><br />

            <br /><br />

            <input type="submit" name="first" id="first" value="|<" onclick="@first(pos)"/>
            <input type="submit" name="prev" id="prev" value="<<" onclick="@prev(pos)"/>
            <input type="submit" name="next" id="next" value=">>" onclick="@next(pos)"/>
            <input type="submit" name="last" id="last" value=">|" />
            <input type="submit" name="borra" id="borra" value="Borrar" />
            <input type="submit" name="Modifica" id="mod" value="Modifica" />
            <input type="submit" name="Nuevo" id="new" value="Nuevo" />



           </form>
        @functions{ 
        int next(int pos) {
                if(IsPost) {
                    pos++;
                    Session["position"] = pos.ToString();
                }
                return pos;
            }

            int prev(int pos) {
                if(IsPost) {
                    pos--;
                    Session["position"] = pos.ToString();
                }
                return pos;
            }

            int first(int pos) {
                if(IsPost) {
                    pos = 0;
                    Session["position"] = pos.ToString();
                }
                return pos;
            }
        }
    }
</body>
```

My problem is when I click on the buttons with the onclick events, all the methods declared in "@functions" are called in reverse order, even when the page is loaded for the first time. I tried to separate them on diferent @functions, use @helper on each method instead of @functions and nothing works.

Anyone have any idea of why is this happening or knows any way to do this propely?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: do you have a controller ? if so you could fetch all the data you need in it and then send the information to the page with a viewmodel and furthermore you can't call c# method with the eventonclick its for javascript method

Comment: I agree: data access is meant to be done in the Controller, or even better: in a data access layer which is called from the Controller. That is why Controllers exist, and why they are separated from Views. Views should receive that data (the `Model`) and turn it into something viewable (e.g. html).

Comment: I made some research and I made it works thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a postback method with your controller

so lets say this is your controller you would do something like this

```
public ActionResult YourPageName(string NextAction)
{
  if(NextAction == "next")
  {
   Session["position"] = (int)Session["position"] + 1;
  }
  elseif(NextAction == "prev")
  {
   Session["position"] = (int)Session["position"] - 1;
  }
  else
  {
   Session["position"] = 0;
  }
  return View();
}
```

And change your View to send the right text with your button value when its clicked on